# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta' Model Query to JSON format

Tags: python, django

Im trying to make the filtered model query into a JSON object so i can handle it better in my template.
This is my code:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def myPostView(request):

    posts = BlogModel.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)

    serialized_posts = serializers.serialize('json', [ posts,])
    print(serialized_posts)

    context = {'posts': posts, 'serialized_posts': serialized_posts}

    return render(request, 'frontend/myposts.html', context)
```

Ive researched and found out that i needed to searialize the data first using the django.core serializer. But it gives me this error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myposts/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location: D:\projects\app\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py in serialize, line 94
```

Any ideas on what im doing wrong? Any help would be appretiated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not wrap this in a list, you should implement this as:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def myPostView(request):
    posts = BlogModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    serialized_posts = serializers.serialize('json', posts)
    print(serialized_posts)
    context = {'posts': posts, 'serialized_posts': serialized_posts}
    return render(request, 'frontend/myposts.html', context)
```

Comment: That was emberrasing haha, damn! But do you know why it console logs like this in my html: ```(index):77 [{&quot;model&quot;: &quot;api.blogmodel&quot;, &quot;pk&quot;: 1, &quot;fields&quot;: {&quot;user&quot;: 1, &quot;title&quot;: &quot;The Hobbit&quot;, &quot;body&quot;: &quot;Boken hobbiten handler om en hobbit som er på et eventyr med en trollmann.&quot;, &quot;created&quot;: &quot;2020-07-15T18:59:15.767Z&quot;}}]```

Comment: @adamkb96: that is because it is escapes it, you should render it with `{{ serialized_posts|safe }}` in the template.

Comment: Thank you again man! Really. And last thing how do i access the fields key? Because it renders like this: ```[{"model": "api.blogmodel", "pk": 1, "fields": {"user": 1, "title": "The Hobbit", "body": "Boken hobbiten handler om en hobbit som er på et eventyr med en trollmann.", "created": "2020-07-15T18:59:15.767Z"}}]``` I see all these [{{ before the json object and i get confused ...

Comment: The `i`-th object can be accessed with `blob[i].fields.user` for example. This can however only be done with the JavaScript functions, since the JSON blob is a simple string.

Comment: Do you mean like this? ```var posts = '{{ serialized_posts|safe }}'

        for(i in posts){
            console.log(posts[i].fields.user)
        }```

Comment: no, `var posts = JSON.parse('{{ serialized_posts|safe }}');`, and then iterate, etc.